# Is there any different evaluation metrics(Performance Metrics) for Deep learning ,Machine, learning and NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, accuracy, metric, mean-squared-error

I'm a little confused about machine learning. I know we can use accuracy, and precision-recall when it comes to a classification problem, and when it comes to regression problems, we usually go with the MSE, RSME etc. For unsupervised learning, we go with a silhouette score ( For machine learning problems) is it the same for Deep learning and NLP can you guys please elaborate . Thank-you

Comment: What do you mean by "is it the same"? As long as the variables have the same nature (e.g. both are categorial in DL/NLP/whatever), the loss function/metric has the same meaning. This does not mean that the same metric/loss is equally suitable for all problems where the variables have the same nature. In fact, in some cases, e.g., the accuracy is not a "good" metric, but the precision or recall are.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.